# Looping through list to compare bulk .docx files using aspose.words python

Tags: python, docx, aspose.words

I am attempting to bulk compare .docx files using aspose.words.

I have a list that I plan on autogenerating by scanning file names.

I then split that list into two lists, new docs and old docs.

I then call my "compare_doc" function which compares the documents, if there are changes, to save a to a new file, else, print something in the console.

All my print statements are running, so I assume the code is working, however, it will only ever save one compared file, even if there are changes in the other set of documents.

Main Script

```
import aspose.words as aw
from datetime import date
from compare_doc import compare_doc

docs = ["Trial Division - Civil - affidavit_new.docx", "Trial Division - Civil - affidavit_old.docx", "test_doc_new.docx", "test_doc_old.docx"]
new_docs = []
old_docs = []

# Create two lists of old and new files
for i in docs:
    if "old" in i:
        old_docs.append(i)

    if "new" in i:
        new_docs.append(i)


# Cycle through the documents and convert to document type
for i, j in new_docs, old_docs:
    doc = aw.Document(i)
    doc1 = aw.Document(j)
    print(doc)
    print(doc1)
    compare_doc(doc, doc1)
```

compare script

```
import aspose.words as aw
from datetime import date

# set additional options
options = aw.comparing.CompareOptions()
options.ignore_formatting = True
options.ignore_headers_and_footers = True
options.ignore_case_changes = True
options.ignore_tables = True
options.ignore_fields = True
options.ignore_comments = True
options.ignore_textboxes = True
options.ignore_footnotes = True

#  date.today(),

def compare_doc(doc, doc1):
    doc.compare(doc1, "user", date.today(), options)
    x = doc.revisions.count
    print(x)
    if x > 0:
        i = 0
        print("Test")
        doc.save(f"compared{i}.docx")
        i = i + 1
    else:
        print("Documents are equal")
```

I am new to python, so any help would be apprecciated.

I was expecting two compare files to save, however only one does.

Comment: This answer might be a bit naive, but couldn't you subsequently run `compare_doc(doc1, doc)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code always saves the comparison result as `compared0.docx` name, so the file is always overridden. Try to modify your code like this:

```py
index = 0
for i, j in new_docs, old_docs:
    doc = aw.Document(i)
    doc1 = aw.Document(j)
    print(doc)
    print(doc1)
    compare_doc(doc, doc1, index)
    index = index + 1;
```

```py
def compare_doc(doc, doc1, index):
    doc.compare(doc1, "user", date.today(), options)
    x = doc.revisions.count
    print(x)
    if x > 0:
        print("Test")
        doc.save(f"compared{index}.docx")
    else:
        print("Documents are equal")
```